# Window Tiling not working in Portrait mode when mouse is on rotated screen

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, tiling

I observed following weird and annoying error:
When ever my mouse is on my rotated monitor (portrait mode) I can't use the shourtcut keys <kbd>Super</kbd> +<kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd>  to tile my windows into halves. However <kbd>Super</kbd> +<kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> to (un)maximaze still work.

This behaviour doens't depend on the position of the actual window or on the screen the window was created on. For example if I open a terminal on my rotated screen and move it (with some keyboard shortcut) to the second (unrotated) monitor the shortcuts won't work. As soon as I move the mouse over too it works. When moving the mouse back to rotated monitor shortcuts won't work again. Same behaviour when I open a window on the normal monitor. When I put both monitors into landscape (=normal) mode shortcuts will work as expected. Is this a known bug? I didn't know what to search for so I would greatly appreciate any hint which could resolve my issue!

PS: I am using standard Ubuntu 18.04 with some shell extensions but the behaviour also occurs when disabling extensions completely.

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: unfortunately not. I switched to manjaro. There the behaviour is similar except when starting the program on the normal screen everything works. Starting the program on the rotated screen is still buggy.